# Javascript - How to extract text with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am new to Regexes. Now I need to write one to suit my needs.
I have this string:

> 1 [00:00:12.00 - 00:01:20.00] Hello there - I've come to help you.

I would somehow need to bring it to this form:

```
const extracted = [
"1",
"[00:00:12.00 - 00:01:20.00]",
"Hello there - I've come to help you."
]
```

I have tried with this approach:

```
const testSubject = "1 [00:00:12.00 - 00:01:20.00] Hello there - I've come to help you."
let result = testSubject.match(/\$[^\$]++\$/)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Invalid regular expression: /$[^$]++$/: Nothing to repeat

I have used this place to get the pattern:
http://regex.inginf.units.it/

Comment: Possessive quantifier `++` is not supported in Javascript besides why are you trying to match `$`?

Comment: Your regex means : "Dollar sign, followed by anything but a dollar sign (repetition), (repetition), dollar sign". Not sure this matches your string. The error comes from the second `(repetition)` that has nothing to repeat before it. Try [regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/)

Comment: Maybe you can split using `\s+(?=\[|(?<=\]\s+))` as a pattern, but you got a better alternative down in the answer section using a capture group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already pointed out by anubhava, possessive quantifiers `++` are not supported in Javascript. You can see the error message in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZpDVc/1) when selecting Javascript at the left panel.

There is no `$` in the string, but if you want to use a negated character class not matching the brackets, you might use a negated character class with a capture group and use split.

```js
const pattern = /\s*(\[[^\][]+])\s*/;
const s = "1 [00:00:12.00 - 00:01:20.00] Hello there - I've come to help you.";
console.log(s.split(pattern))
```